# How to import class from another module in android studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I created two modules in single android project, named it x and y.

1. Module x has a class Egg (Package: com.example.x)
2. Module y has a class Foo (Package: com.example.y)

Now I want to import class Foo in the class Egg, for which I wrote the statement mentioned below in class Egg

```
Import com.example.y.Foo;
```

Now, Foo is not recognized by android.

Questions,

> Is it possible to import Class from a different module using just
>   import statement?
>
> Do I need to create library of Module y and then import created
>   library into module x?

Or may the solution is something else.

Comment: Is `Foo` public? And `i` should be in small case in `import`.

Comment: Did you add that module to the dependency in gradle file?

Comment: @prerakSola yes Foo is public, and i is small.

Comment: Can you please add the code of both the classes in your question?

Comment: @prudhvi No I didn't add the module to dependency. I will try and then let you know.

Answer (score 100, accepted):

Make sure of the following:

In settings.gradle, you should have: `include ':x', ':y'`.

In x/build.gradle, you should add y as a dependency:

```
dependencies {
        compile project(':y')
        // other dependencies
}
```

Comment: Make sure of creating Module y with Android Library or replace " apply plugin: 'com.android.application' "with " apply plugin: 'com.android.library' " in gradle file.

Comment: How can I refer my code from another of my modules? I mean I have a `moduleA` where I use `moduleB` and `moduleB` uses a third `moduleC` but when I refer a class from `moduleC` in `moduleA` (control + click) it is showing me the compiled `.class` instead of my `.java` class from my `moduleC`. Do you have some idea to solve this? Thanks!

Comment: 'compile' is deprecated; use 'implementation'. And this goes into app build.gradle, not the module's build.gradle.

Answer (score 13):

Now when you create new module,the *settings.gradle* file add automatically this module.After that u should add this line:

```
    dependencies {
    implementation(
    ...,
    ..,
            project(":y")
)
}
```

Comment: I can apply this solution for only library module

Answer (score 10):

Combining and correcting two previous answers the best solution is to add this single line to x/build.gradle -> dependencies

```
implementation project(':y')
```

`compile project()` - is deprecated and won't work anymore

If you want to implement just a single module there is no need to use `implementation(..., .., project(":y")` structure.

Comment: goes into app build.gradle, not module's build.gradle