# Class symbol not recognized after module added

Tags: android

This is the [library](https://github.com/GoodieBag/CarouselPicker) I am using. But I need to change the style java code. But since it's an external dependency, the file is read-only.

I learned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30344053/how-do-you-edit-a-dependency-external-library-in-android-studio) that if I add it as module I can then edit the file. I did that. I added the module successfully.

But now, the problem is how do I use the class from the library module. For instance, in my MainActivity.java, when I declared the global variable `CarouselPicker carousel`, Android Studio said 'Cannot resolve symbol CarouselPicker' and there is no Alt+Enter option to import any class. CarouselPicker is a class in the library. It worked when I used the library using compile in dependencies.

EDIT:

This is my Android file structure:

[screenshot of Android file structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qeyP7.png)

This is the dependencies block code of my build.gradle(Module:app):

[screenshot of code bloack](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wz3FA.png)

In my Share.java file, I tried to import CarouselPicker, this is what I get for Alt+Enter:

[What Alt+Enter gave me.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HxRBi.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to import class from another module in android studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34419962/how-to-import-class-from-another-module-in-android-studio)

Answer (score 0):

please make sure that you have added the dependency line of the module in the gradle

see this for more details [How to import class from another module in android studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34419962/6118808)

Comment: I added compile project (':CarouselPicker-master'); in the dependencies of my project. I synced. Then in my class, I wrote import com.example.android.myProject.CarouselPicker-master. It says cannot resolve symbol CarouselPicker.

Comment: try to type only `CarouselPicker` then put the cursor on it and hit alt+enter then android studio will automatically put the correct package name

Comment: Nope, Alt+Enter doesn't bring up anything.

Comment: try to delete the .idea and .gradle folders from your project directory then clean and build the project

Comment: now I see what is the problem....you should write `CarouselPicker` inside any function of your class then put the cursor on it ...then hit alt+enter ...then it should work